# e2e tests on pages that require login

Tags: angular, protractor, redux, ngrx

Hi have an application with these pages and their corresponding e2e tests:

```
/login 
/products
/users
```

I have to be logged in to test the products page or the users page.

Should I run the whole login scenario before each of these tests ?

Or should I modify the state of the application as "logged in" before running the products or users e2e tests like in the example below?

```
//products.e2e.ts
beforeEach(() => { 
    browser.executeScript(/* set logged in state to true here */);
}
```

Comment: That script would be closely tied to the implementation of "logged in", which seems like a bad idea. If possible, have the user log in through the UI `beforeAll`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write an separate home/login page and call it once in each suite and then do'nt login/log out during each spec.Just make sure using beforeAll or afterAll you always start a spec from a clean state(home page).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by making a separate file for login and then call the login function in your protractor.conf configuration file.

```
    var Login = require('login.page.js');
    var login = new Login();
    login.login();
```